# Failed to find user in SharePoint after the user is added to a team in MS Teams using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-teams

We added a user to a team using MS Graph API

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/<team-id>/members
Content-type: application/json

{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
    "roles": ["member"],
    "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('<user-id>')"
}
```

Then we wanted to add this user to a SiteGroup in SharePoint connected to the team. We want to use these SiteGroups to control access of uploaded files.
Unfortunately MS Graph API cannot support this operation. Thus we have to use SharePoint REST API.
First of all we have to find the user in SharePoint.

```
https://<my-domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-id>/_api/Web/SiteUsers?$filter=Email eq '<user-email>'
```

But this call returns an empty list.

We can add the user manually using SharePoint admin tool: `https://<my-domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-id>/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=<SiteGroup-id>`
The Sharepoint can see this new user but the REST API cannot.

One day later the user appeared in the list of SiteUsers:

```
https://<my-domain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-id>/_api/web/SiteUsers
```

Is there a faster way to add user to a team and also add this user to a SharePoint SiteGroup?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any other faster way to  do so

Comment: When the user is added to the team in Teams, the user is, at the same time, added to Group Members which has "Contribute" permissions to the SharePoint site connected with that team. From that standpoint, it seems redundant to add user explicitly to SharePoint, as it already has permissions

Comment: You are right, but we have to hide some documents from the most of members of the team.  So we want to create a sitegroup to allow its members to access these special documents.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT What is the synchronization time between Graph API and SharePoint?

Comment: There is no such specific time limit. It might take from few minutes to few hours as well.